# Correct Ethernet Jack + Magnetics for 100Base-TX

Tags: ethernet, phy, rj45

I've been shopping around for Ethernet jacks for use in a personal project. The part specifically states that it's internal PHYs are 100BASE-TX/10BASE-T/Te IEEE 802.3

I understand the basic difference between [100Base-T and 100Base-TX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#Copper), but I guess I don't understand why an Ethernet jack and/or the magnetics need to be spec'd for this. It's all getting clocked through the wire at ~125MHz, right?

[Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/modular-connectors-jacks-with-magnetics/365?k=&pkeyword=&pv405=1774&pv405=1760&FV=ffe0016d&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) seems to differentiate between -TX and -T. [Mouser's parametric search](https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/Modular-Connectors-Ethernet-Connectors/_/N-wos3?P=1yvgcdj&Ns=Pricing%7C0) doesn't mention anything like the connection speed and is very unhelpful, showing me stuff with and without magnetics.

The 100Base-TX jacks with mags seem to be more expensive than -T (on Digikey) so that leads me to believe some timing requirement of 100Base-TX require entirely different magnetics specs or something. But if it doesn't matter, I certainly don't want to spend $4 on a jack when I could spend only $1.60.

Any advice? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: for $1 you need a chinese supplier (look up for AICO). Western companies, even Wurth, will cost you $2-4. On the other hand, talking to them is much easier, you will get samples quickly...

Comment: I was referring to the cheapest option shown by Digikey at the above link. It's a J1B1211CCD from WIZnet. Thanks for the tip. I'll check out AICO and Wurth.

Comment: The question shouldn't be whether to get a 100baseT vs 100baseTX jack. Almost all implementations are TX anyway. You should select the jack+magnetics to use based on what your specific PHY chip asks for, because they have different requirements. Which PHY chip are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the basic difference between 100Base-T and 100Base-TX ...

Are you sure? Maybe between 10BASE-T (original Ethernet) and 100BASE-TX (Fast Ethernet)?  Or between 1000BASE-T (Gigabit Ethernet) and 100BASE-TX?

Both 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX work over two twisted pairs at once. While 1000BASE-T works over four pairs at once.

Making it shorter, people often write simply but mistakenly 10/100BASE-TX or 10/100BASE-T instead of proper 10BASE-T/100BASE-TX or 10BASE-Te/100BASE-TX to indicate that a MagJack support both (original and Fast) protocols.

Therefore:

- On the Digikey page you referred to, there is no difference between selects in the Application field, select both and choose between all the will-be-shown possibilities;
- On the Mouser page, there is no "simple" way to filter out only Fast ones.